# Возникает ошибка в инструментах разработки

Tags: javascript

В инструментах разработки Opera и Google Chrome выдаёт ошибку:

> test2.html:16 Uncaught ReferenceError: Robot is not defined
>   at test2.html:16

вот код:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang ="en">
<head>
<meta charset ="utf-8">
<title>est timeCounter</title>
<script>
"use strict";

function SpaceRobot(name, year, owner, homePlanet) {
this.name = name;
this.year = year;
this.owner = owner;
this.homePlanet = homePlanet;

}
SpaceRobot.prototype = new Robot;

SpaceRobot.prototype.speak = function() {
alert(this.name + " says Sir, If I may venture an opinion...");
};

SpaceRobot.prototype.pilot = function() {
alert(this.name + " says Thrusters? Are they important?");
};
var c3po = new SpaceRobot("C3PO", 1977, "Luke Skywalker", "Tatooine");
c3po.speak();
c3po.pilot();
console.log(c3po.name + " was made by " + c3po.maker);
var simon = new SpaceRobot("Simon", 2009, "Carla Diana", "Earth");
simon.makeCoffee();
simon.blinkLights();
simon.speak();



</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: и что не понятно? нет у тебя `Robot` нигде. не объявлен

Answer (score 2):

в тексте ошибки и кроется ответ)
в html документе в строке

```
SpaceRobot.prototype = new Robot;
```

Robot - неизвестное для браузера. Вернее не объявленная ранее, м.б. нужно было подключить какой-нибудь дом файл? а-ля:

```
<script src="какой-тоскрипт.js"></script>
```